# Force to show all labels

Tags: anychart

I have an Doughnut chart with
chart.labels().position("outside");

It's showing the percentage fine for the fields with a lot of data.
Is it possible to "force" show all of them ?

Even when I go to full screen, it's not showing.

[I attached image on my chart with missing labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sri8z.png)

Looking for "Force show" or Min/Max settings for labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tweak [`outsideLabelsCriticalAngle`](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.charts.Pie#outsideLabelsCriticalAngle).

```js
anychart.onDocumentLoad(() => {
  let data = [
    { x: "A", value: 93.3 },
    { x: "B", value: 5.9 },
    { x: "C", value: 0.5 },
    { x: "D", value: 0.3 }
  ];

  let chart = anychart.pie(data);

  chart.container("container");
  chart.innerRadius("80%");
  chart.outsideLabelsCriticalAngle(100); // <--- HERE
  chart.labels().position("outside");
  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-pie.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for :)